# Undefined variable while retrieving variable from action form scripts

Tags: php, forms

```
<?php 
    if($_POST) {
         //not empty
         //atleast 6 characters long

         $errors = array();
         //start validation
         if(empty($_POST['email'])) {
             $errors['email1'] = "<p style='color:red;font-family: BCompset, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:30px;'>Please write down your email!</p>";
         }

         //check errors
         if(count($errors) == 0) {
             //redirect to success pages
             header("Location: success.php");
             exit();
          }
    }

    ?>
    <form action="" method="POST" class="searchform" dir="ltr">
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your email address"/>
      <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i></button>
      <p><?php if(isset($errors['email1'])) echo $errors['email1']; ?></p>
      <?php if(count($errors) == 0){
         echo "<p id='para' dir='rtl'>
         You can add your email to get the latest updates.</p>";
       } ?>
    </form>
```

I want to show the paragraph with id='para' (line 31) when the form is not submitted yet and if the user clicked on submit button without entering his email address ,the error message will pop up and that paragraph will not be shown anymore.. To do this I set the `if(count($errors) == 0)` but I get the **Undefined variable** error message on line 31. Maybe because I can not take a variable from action scripts until the form is not submitted. Any solution to my problem please?

Comment: `if(empty($errors))` may help in this case.

Comment: by this way error message will be gone but the paragraph still can not be shown!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:-

```
<?php 
 $errors = array();
if($_POST)
    {
        //not empty
        //atleast 6 characters long
        //start validation

        if(empty($_POST['email']))
        {
            $errors['email1'] = "<p style='color:red;font-family: BCompset, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:30px;'>Please write down your email!</p>";
        }

        //check errors
        if(count($errors) == 0)
        {
            //redirect to success pages
            header("Location: success.php");
            exit();
        }
    }

?>
<form action="" method="POST" class="searchform" dir="ltr">
                                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your email address"/>
                                <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i></button>
                                <p><?php if(isset($errors['email1'])) echo $errors['email1']; ?></p>
                   <?php if(count($errors) == 0){echo "<p id='para' dir='rtl'>You can add your email to get the latest updates.</p>";}?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `<form>` is outside the `if($_POST)`, so it will be shown whether or not `$_POST` was set. But `$errors` is only set inside the `if`. There are two simple ways to fix this:

1. Move the initialization of `$errors` to before the `if`.
2. Use `if(empty($errors)` instead of `if(count($errors) == 0)`. `empty()` doesn't complain if the variable isn't set.